# Flutter call method channel when app onBackGround , terminated with flutter_background_service

Tags: android, flutter, background-service

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service for my background service.I  call Method Channel inside my service to update my floating widget(This widget write by android native code) but it not working,I have tried to call the channel method inside flutter ui and it works correctly.After researching, I found that Method inside MainActivity
can only be called by main Isolate(Flutter UI). **The question is how can I call method channel when running flutter_backgroud_service**

Comment: By any chance have you resolved this issue? please share your opinion.

Comment: I am also waiting for this answer.